# "...she had not been attending class" or "...she was not attending class"?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-continuous

What is the difference between the following two sentences:

> 1. Betty failed the final test because she **had not been attending** class.
> 2. Betty failed the final test because she **was not attending** class.

Is the second sentence incorrect because Betty did not fail the same minute or hour when she was not attending her class?

Edit: I had read this example on a website "He was tired because he was exercising so hard." As I understand, this sentence emphasizes that he was tired because he was exercising at the same time. In my example "Betty failed the final test because she was not attending class." I have thought the same that the two verbs failed and attend happened the same time. which for me is impossible then I thought the sentence is incorrect.

Comment: What did you mean by _"....because Betty did not fail the same minute or hour when she was not attending her class."_? Can you clarify that?

Comment: I have changed the sentences

Comment: The use off a continuous tense generally indicates that the -ing activity was happening both **before** and **after** the event. If it's a recurring event it doesn't have to happen at **exactly** the same time as the event. For example, if the class is every Monday and the exam is on a Wednesday, the exam would not be at exactly the same time as the class, but you can still use a continuous tense "She was attending classes at the time of the exam".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of past perfect continuous indicates that the classes were **before** the exam. Past continuous would indicate that the exam occurred **in the middle of** the classes that she missed.

Past perfect continuous is probably the intended meaning.

> "Betty failed the final test because she had not been attending class."

---

Regarding your edit:

The use of a past continuous generally indicates that the -ing activity was happening both before and after the event. If it's a recurring event it doesn't have to happen at exactly the same time as the event. For example, if the class is every Monday and the exam is on a Wednesday, the exam would not be at exactly the same time as the class, but you can still use past continuous:

> She was attending classes at the time of the exam

What makes past perfect continuous the most appropriate in this case is that it's a **final exam**, which suggests that **all** of the classes were before the exam.